# Sorting an string column without specific pattern in Sql Server numerically and alphabetically, separetly

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a string column with values like '56LU20Q' and '56LU5Q' and 'RW9'.
I want to sort this column and get the sorted result:  '56LU5Q', '56LU20Q', and 'RW9'.

I would appreciate any help and comments.

I wrote a function in SQL Server, but getting the result is very slow!

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Catalogs;
CREATE TABLE #Catalogs(CatalogNumber NVARCHAR(200))
INSERT INTO #Catalogs (CatalogNumber) VALUES('56LU20Q'),('56LU5Q'),('RW9');
SELECT ISNULL(IIF(TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT) IS NULL,
                ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(LEFT(L.CatalogNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber )) AS BIGINT), NULL)
                , TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT)
                ),
                10000
        ) AS Number, 

       STUFF(L.CatalogNumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber), ''),

       LTRIM(PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', 
                STUFF(L.CatalogNumber, 
                        1, 
                        PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', STUFF(L.CatalogNumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber), '')), 
                        ''
                    )
       )),

       STUFF(STUFF(L.CatalogNumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber), ''), PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber), 200, ''),

       STUFF(STUFF(L.CatalogNumber, 1, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber), ''), 1, PATINDEX('%[A-z][^A-z]%', L.CatalogNumber), ''),

       SUBSTRING(IIF(TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT) IS NULL,
       LTRIM(LEFT(L.CatalogNumber, LEN(L.CatalogNumber) - PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber )))
       , NULL),
       0,
       LEN(IIF(TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT) IS NULL,
                ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(LEFT(L.CatalogNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber )) AS BIGINT), 0)
                , 0
                    )) + 1
        ) AS letter1, 

        SUBSTRING(L.CatalogNumber, 
                    LEN(ISNULL(IIF(TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT) IS NULL,
                        ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(LEFT(L.CatalogNumber, PATINDEX('%[0-9][^0-9]%', L.CatalogNumber )) AS BIGINT), NULL)
                        , TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT)
                            ),0)
                        ),
                    LEN(ISNULL(IIF(TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT) IS NULL,
                        ISNULL(TRY_PARSE(LEFT(L.CatalogNumber, PATINDEX('%[A-z,_-][^A-z,_-]%', L.CatalogNumber )) AS BIGINT), NULL)
                        , TRY_PARSE(L.CatalogNumber AS BIGINT)
                                )
                            ,0)
                        )
            ) AS FirstLetter,
       L.CatalogNumber
FROM #Catalogs AS L
ORDER BY Number
```

Comment: And what's the sorting logic behind your function? Also, you didn't ask any question

Comment: Ideally you should separate this column out into separate columns, then you can sort each individually.

Comment: `getting the result is very slow!` that's caused by the unconventional data itself. By violating the most basic rule, 1 cell=1 value, it's no longer possible to query or sort the values individually and take advantage of indexes. No matter what function is used, the server will have to parse every single value, collect the partial results (spool) into tempdb and only then try to sort them, without the benefit of an index

Comment: Let's say you could somehow convert the data to a JSON string, `[56,'LU',5,'Q']` and tried to search by individual items, `ORDER BY JSON_VALUE(json,'$.[0]'), JSON_VALUE(json,'$.[1]')...`. You'd *still* get bad performance because the server would have to scan all rows to extract the values before sorting

Comment: @Charlieface
Yes, but I couldn't separate it correctly.
I put what I did for the separation.
I just need three new columns the first and third ones are integers and the second one is a string.